# How to make TEXT in a white div fully transparent so as to show the background?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, transparency

What I am trying to do is that in a div with a white opaque background, I want the text to be fully transparent so that it can show the body's background.

This is my source code so far:

```css
body, html {
  color: #FFF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: url(http://forums.windowscentral.com/attachments/windows-10/104338d1431267538t-windows-spotlight-lockscreen-96-.jpg) center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -215px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to make the text invisible and show the palm trees wallpaper, and also to make the div's background white.

I have tried:

```
.center {
color: transparent;
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

But it only makes both the text and the background white.

<strike>Example of what I am trying to achieve:</strike>

Focus only on the button (imagine that's the div) that has a white background. Imagine that the blue color (of both the body background and the text) is the background image.

Is this possible using just CSS and HTML? I don't mind javascript or jquery though.

---

**Nevermind, thanks to @JokerFan, I have found a solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CZX123/b5dyvm27/4/).**

Note: This only works in webkit browsers.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - if the text was transparent you'd see the background *of the button*, not whatever's beyond it.

Comment: That's what I want to do, make the text see whatever's beyond it

Comment: Do I have to add like another HTML element or something?

Comment: Why don't you just make the text the appropriate colour?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nevermind, just go to the link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CZX123/b5dyvm27/2/). You will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are expecting something as follows,

```css
body, html {
  color: #FFF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: url(http://forums.windowscentral.com/attachments/windows-10/104338d1431267538t-windows-spotlight-lockscreen-96-.jpg) center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -215px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
span {
  background: url(http://forums.windowscentral.com/attachments/windows-10/104338d1431267538t-windows-spotlight-lockscreen-96-.jpg) center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <span>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you figured out what I wanted! However, just a correction, change your current `span` css to: `span {
    background: url(http://forums.windowscentral.com/attachments/windows-10/104338d1431267538t-windows-spotlight-lockscreen-96-.jpg) center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    display:block;
  }`

Comment: And also remove unnecessary styles such as `#container` and remove the extra styles in the html, body part.

Comment: Just improve your answer and I will do it.

Comment: @CZX Thanks,Edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Set `#fff` to text color also

```
.center {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no color value the `transparent` but background does.

For you layout, you can just use border using white color and apply the background of the button as transparent. And use color white for the text instead of transparent.